# I want to check that a textbox doesnt have more than one decimal point (in gridview) without using validation or javascript

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

I want to check that a textbox doesnt have more than one decimal point (in gridview) without using validation or javascript,

I want check this on textchanged...

I have kept validation, filter ajax extender and all that but I wnat it here

```
  protected void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go...

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

protected void txtqty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  decimal number;
  string value = txtqty.Text;

  if (decimal.TryParse(value, out number))
  {
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*");

    if (!rx.IsMatch(value))
    {
      Response.Write("error");
    }
    Response.Write("good");
  }
  else
  {
    Response.Write("error");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim number As String = CType(BOMGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("editSpareFac"), TextBox).Text.ToString

If Regex.IsMatch(number, "^[0-9]+\.[0-9]$") Then
   SpareFac = CType(CType(BOMGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("editSpareFac"), TextBox).Text, Double)
Else
   lblErr.Text = "Special characters and alphabets are not allowed !!"
   Exit Sub
End
```